# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit, ios8, exc-bad-access

I have been looking on this site and across google for about a week now trying to solve a bug in my app. It dosent look like memory management is the issue and breakpoints/instruments with zombies dosent return anything. All I have been able to figure out is that the issue stems from this block of code. When the app is run under certain circumstances it returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS on my main.m. I think this is the issue but thanks in advance for just looking over it!

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (!gameOver && gameStarted) {

[lines runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]];
dotDrawn = NO;

UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

pos2x = positionInScene.x;
pos2y = positionInScene.y;

lines = [SKShapeNode node];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, pos1x, pos1y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pos2x, pos2y);

lines.path = path;
lines.strokeColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[lines setLineWidth:3];

[self addChild:lines];
}
```

}

Comment: add an exception breakpoint and post any crash message printed to the log. Note that you leak the cgpath object, you have to cgpathrelease it.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'll try the breakpoint exception when I get a chance later today but where would I cgpathrelease ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: After the lines.path = path; line. You still "own" the path so you have to release it. ARC doesn't automatically release core foundation objects like CGPath.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Hey, I tried both the breakpoint exception and adding CGPathRelease(path); but the crash and exception still occur. If you have any other ideas I would love to hear them but if not thanks for at least looking over it!

Comment: The exception breakpoint should show you the line of code closest to the error where source code is still available. Which line does Xcode highlight when it crashes?

Comment: The exception breakpoint does absolutely nothing. It still crashes and highlights my main.m with error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x500000000000018)" Also there is nothing that is logged to console if that help you at all.

Comment: in that case it's harder to narrow it down. Your best bet is to remove parts of your project until the error goes away - in that case the error must be related to the most recently removed part.

Comment: That was how I was originally able to narrow it down to this method within the code base. I am probably going to try to redo the whole system for drawing the line in a test project and copy over the code. Fingers crossed that it works but thanks anyways for the help!

Comment: I'm having similar problems, and there is a similar question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26118928/1332415). From there you can follow a link trail of people reporting a similar problem after upgrading to iOS7.1.  I'm not sure where the rabbit hole leads, but I know this: I can avoid all my crashes by recursively removing children from their parents before removing the parents.  Try getting rid of your `SKAction` for removing from parent, and do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23570896/1332415).  Maybe a workaround until we can figure this out.

Comment: Thank @KarlVoskuil While the solution that you suggested did not work (threw another EXC_BAD_ACCESS) I did notice that it was called over 200 times on the thread log before the app crashed. Do you know of a solution where I could keep this code block from updating as often?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I started messing with it again and if I comment out the [lines runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]]; line then it no longer crashes. I have no clue if this helps but once again thanks for the help!

Comment: @Appleguy1999, if you replace it with a simple `[lines removeFromParent]`, does it crash?  I spent some time trying to figure out what it was about my so-called workaround that was working for me, and I think it's **just** the elimination of the `[SKAction removeFromParent]`.  I'm getting good results from that kind of change.  In fact, I think I might enter this as an answer, because it's working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, with the same symptoms: The code worked in iOS7.1 but started crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS8; trying to trace the source of the bad access with zombies doesn't help.

Here's what's working for me to fix the problem: Eliminate all uses of `[SKAction removeFromParent]`.

For your example, that would just mean replacing `[lines runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]]` with `[lines removeFromParent]`.

A little trickier is replacing something like this:

```
[myNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[ [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.0],
                                        [SKAction removeFromParent] ]]];
```

with this:

```
[myNode runAction:[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.0] completion:^{
    [myNode removeFromParent];
}];
```

Edit: Using the right search terms, I found a link to [another question describing the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25932291/1332415).

Comment: Thanks! This was a life saver and I was finally able to stop the timer for work on this one bug at many, many hours. Once again, Thanks!